# "requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages" when I try to create a web app symfony 6 project

Tags: symfony6

When I try to create a web app symfony 6 project, I have this error message :"Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages" and dependencies seems not to be installed (Lot of folders in my project are missing).

MacBook-Pro-de-Ludovic:programmation lesage$ symfony new --webapp  projetWeb

- Creating a new Symfony project with Composer
  (running /Users/lesage/Documents/ludovic/programmation/composer.phar create-project symfony/skeleton /Users/lesage/Documents/ludovic/programmation/projetWeb  --no-interaction)
- Setting up the project under Git version control
  (running git init /Users/lesage/Documents/ludovic/programmation/projetWeb)

  (running /Users/lesage/Documents/ludovic/programmation/composer.phar require webapp --no-interaction)

./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update symfony/webapp-pack
Loading composer repositories with package information
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "6.2.*"
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- symfony/webapp-pack[v1.0.0, ..., v1.1.1] require symfony/orm-pack * -> satisfiable by symfony/orm-pack[v1.0.0, ..., v1.2.0, v2.0.0, v2.1.0, v2.2.0, v2.3.0].
- symfony/orm-pack[v1.0.8, v2.0.0, ..., v2.3.0] require doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle * -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle[1.0.0, ..., v1.3.2, v2.0.0, ..., 2.2.3, 3.0.0, ..., 3.2.2].
- symfony/orm-pack[v2.1.0, ..., v2.2.0] require symfony/proxy-manager-bridge * -> satisfiable by symfony/proxy-manager-bridge[v6.2.0].
- doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle[3.2.1, ..., 3.2.2] require doctrine/migrations ^3.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/migrations[3.2.0, ..., 3.5.4].
- symfony/proxy-manager-bridge v6.2.0 requires friendsofphp/proxy-manager-lts ^1.0.2 -> satisfiable by friendsofphp/proxy-manager-lts[v1.0.2, ..., v1.0.13].
- doctrine/migrations[3.3.1, ..., 3.5.4] require friendsofphp/proxy-manager-lts ^1.0 -> satisfiable by friendsofphp/proxy-manager-lts[v1.0.0, ..., v1.0.13].
- friendsofphp/proxy-manager-lts[v1.0.4, ..., v1.0.13] require laminas/laminas-code ~3.4.1|^4.0 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-code[3.4.1, 4.0.0, ..., 4.8.0].
- symfony/orm-pack[v1.1.0, ..., v1.2.0] require doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle ^2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle[v2.0.0, ..., 2.2.3].
- laminas/laminas-code 3.4.1 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.3.0-dev) does not satisfy that requirement.
- doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle[v2.0.0, ..., 2.2.1] require php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.3.0-dev) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laminas/laminas-code[4.0.0, ..., 4.4.3] require php ^7.4 || ~8.0.0 -> your php version (8.3.0-dev) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laminas/laminas-code[4.5.0, ..., 4.7.1] require php >=7.4, <8.2 -> your php version (8.3.0-dev) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laminas/laminas-code 4.8.0 requires php ~8.1.0 || ~8.2.0 -> your php version (8.3.0-dev) does not satisfy that requirement.
- friendsofphp/proxy-manager-lts[v1.0.0, ..., v1.0.3] require symfony/filesystem ^4.4.17|^5.0 -> found symfony/filesystem[v4.4.17, ..., v4.4.42, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.13] but the package is fixed to v6.2.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- doctrine/migrations 3.2.0 requires psr/log ^1.1.3 -> found psr/log[1.1.3, 1.1.4] but the package is fixed to 3.0.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- doctrine/migrations[3.2.1, ..., 3.3.0] require symfony/console ^3.4 || ^4.4.16 || ^5.0 -> found symfony/console[v3.4.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.4.16, ..., v4.4.49, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.17] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (6.2.*).
- doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle 1.0.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.1 -> found symfony/framework-bundle[v2.1.0, ..., v2.8.52] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (6.2.*).
- doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle[1.0.1, ..., v1.2.1] require symfony/framework-bundle ~2.3|~3.0 -> found symfony/framework-bundle[v2.3.0, ..., v2.8.52, v3.0.0, ..., v3.4.47] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (6.2.*).
- doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle[v1.3.0, ..., v1.3.2] require symfony/framework-bundle ~2.7|~3.3|~4.0 -> found symfony/framework-bundle[v2.7.0, ..., v2.8.52, v3.3.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.0.0, ..., v4.4.49] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (6.2.*).
- doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle[2.2.2, ..., 2.2.3, 3.0.2, ..., 3.2.0] require symfony/framework-bundle ~3.4|~4.0|~5.0 -> found symfony/framework-bundle[v3.4.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.0.0, ..., v4.4.49, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.17] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (6.2.*).
- doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle[3.0.0, ..., 3.0.1] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.3.0-dev) does not satisfy that requirement.
- symfony/orm-pack[v1.0.0, ..., v1.0.7] require php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.3.0-dev) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Root composer.json requires symfony/webapp-pack * -> satisfiable by symfony/webapp-pack[v1.0.0, ..., v1.1.1].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require symfony/webapp-pack:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require symfony/webapp-pack:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

unable to run /Users/lesage/Documents/ludovic/programmation/composer.phar require webapp --no-interaction

```
My composer.json
```

{
"type": "project",
"license": "proprietary",
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"prefer-stable": true,
"require": {
"php": ">=8.1",
"ext-ctype": "*",
"ext-iconv": "*",
"symfony/console": "6.2.*",
"symfony/dotenv": "6.2.*",
"symfony/flex": "^2",
"symfony/framework-bundle": "6.2.*",
"symfony/runtime": "6.2.*",
"symfony/yaml": "6.2.*"
},
"require-dev": {
},
"config": {
"allow-plugins": {
"symfony/flex": true,
"symfony/runtime": true
},
"sort-packages": true
},
"autoload": {
"psr-4": {
"App\": "src/"
}
},
"autoload-dev": {
"psr-4": {
"App\Tests\": "tests/"
}
},
"replace": {
"symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
"symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
"symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
"symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
"symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
"symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
"symfony/polyfill-php81": "*"
},
"scripts": {
"auto-scripts": {
"cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
"assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
},
"post-install-cmd": [
"@auto-scripts"
],
"post-update-cmd": [
"@auto-scripts"
]
},
"conflict": {
"symfony/symfony": "*"
},
"extra": {
"symfony": {
"allow-contrib": false,
"require": "6.2.*"
}
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I resolved the problem. I had a conflict with an old version of php. So, I uninstall et reinstall PHP and it works fine.

Comment: I don't think this question will provide any insight for other users. I recommend removing it.